# Why does Cesare Borgia keep saying he can not die at the hands of man?

Tags: assassins-creed

Everytime Cesare Borgia faces his death such as in a fight or after his father tried to poison him (not sure if it was successful) he always says that he can not die at the hands on man

> until Ezio throws him off a castle leaving "god" decided if he lands safely or not.

Is this just vain egotism on his part thinking no one can best him? or did he receive some sort of vision of his death and he just assumed it was a natural one? does this compare to his real life counterpart?

Comment: It's likely he just had a god complex, however according to the Facebook game "Project Legacy" (which I believe is considered canon), there is some suggestion that Cesare may have owned the Shroud of Turin (his name is one of the four parts of the shroud's Mnemonic Set, all the other names required are known former owners/users of the shroud, and the shroud was definitely used on Giovanni Borgia at some point). The Shroud was one of the Pieces of Eden, with healing and perhaps even resurrection powers.